# Specific addons not showing in addons menu when installed

Tags: add-on, error

I know this has been asked over and over, but I'll try myself because my case is a bit different.
**Only some addons don't show up**, for this example I tried to install the new **Mixer addon from Ubisoft**. I click on the .zip file, and it shows that it has been installed, but when trying to search for it to activate it in the addons menu, the addon doesn't show up, *not even in the experimental section*.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I just checked my addon folder and it is there but somethings wrong... I'm in 2.83.0 on Mac. What about you?

Comment: When referring to an addon recommend adding a link.  Also suggest listing more "specific" addons than one. Have you raised the issue here? https://github.com/ubisoft/mixer/issues